# How to acces string data in nested dictionary with Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, rpc

From a RPC-Server i get the following response:

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": {"errorMessage": "'DUT':1'IMEI':123456789,'debug_msg':11", "result": "True", "version": "2"}, "id": 2}
```

How can I get the value of "IMEI" in the nested dictionary, which answer is "123456789"?

I tried:

```
response = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": {"errorMessage": "'DUT':1'IMEI':123456789,'debug_msg':11", "result": "True", "version": "2"}, "id": 2}
errorMessage = response["result"]["errorMessage"]
print (errorMessage[1])
```

But I only get the second char of the string DUT.

Comment: `response["result"]["errorMessage"][1]` *is* `'D'`, I don't know why you'd expect something different. You'd have to *parse* that string, e.g. to a dictionary `{'DUT': 1, 'IMEI': 123456789, ...}`, to get items out of it by name.

Comment: `errorMessage.split("'IMEI':")[1].split("'")[0].rstrip(",")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem to fix is the inconsistent formatting of the returned string, this can be done for this case with the `replace` method of the `string` class:

```py
response = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": {"errorMessage": "'DUT':1'IMEI':123456789,'debug_msg':11", "result": "True", "version": "2"}, "id": 2}

errorMessage = "{"+response["result"]["errorMessage"].replace("'IMEI'",",'IMEI'").replace("'","\"")+"}"
```

Then you can read the string using the `loads` method from the `json` module.

```py
from json import loads
errorDict = loads(errorMessage)
print (errorDict["IMEI"])
```

Comment: Hi Ronald! Your answer is mostly code. Please add some description to it.

Comment: OK I'll try to be more explicit.